# Conditional Compiler Type definition

Tags: c#, .net

What I want to do is create a user defined type with an #if #else so that later in the code, I can just reference that type when doing variable declarations.  A simple example is below

```
#define INT_ONLY
//#define LONG_ONLY

#if INT_ONLY
    using type_var as int;
#else
    using type_var as long;
#endif

private sub main() {
  type_var x = 0;
}
```

What I looking for is the correct syntax if this type of operation is allowed.

Comment: Jared is right; this is a strange thing to do in C#. Can you explain why you're doing this? If what you want is a "processor-natural-sized integer" because you are interoperating with unmanaged code that takes a pointer-sized integer as a handle then use IntPtr; it's usually not a good idea to try to roll your own like this.

Comment: The example I gave was just a simple snippet to get the right syntax. What I was hoping to do was implement the using within a class that implements generics. One of the variables can be of type Array<T> or of Array<Cache<T>> depending of the #ifdef declarations. I implement array locking when doing iteration and would like to avoid having to #ifdef 2 ( Array<T> lock = and Array<Cache<T>> lock = ) using clauses when getting the lock of the array. But I cannot setup the using clause inside the class and the T is not define if the using clause if outside the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is the following

```
#if INT_ONLY
using type_var = System.Int32;
#else
using type_var = System.Int64;
#endif
```

Although I am curious why you're doing this?  It seems like it will produce a lot of user confusion.  I think a better solution would be to create a wrapper type which hides it's storage type using an `#ifdef` as an implementation detail (much the way `IntPtr` does)

```
struct type_var {
#if INT_ONLY
  int m_value;
#else
  long m_value;
#endif

  public type_var(int i) {
    m_value = i;
  }

#if INT_ONLY
  public type_var(long l) {
    m_value = l;
  }
#endif

  public static operator type_var(int i) {
    return new type_var(i);
  }

#if INT_ONLY
  public static operator type_var(long i) {
    return new type_var(i);
  }
#endif

// Etc ...    
}
```

Comment: The example I gave was just a simple snippet to get the right syntax.  What I was hoping to do was implement the using within a class that implements generics.  One of the variables can be of type Array<T> or of Array<Cache<T>> depending of the #ifdef declarations.  I implement array locking when doing iteration and would like to avoid having to #ifdef 2 ( Array<T> lock = and Array<Cache<T>> lock = ) using clauses when getting the lock of the array.  But I cannot setup the using clause inside the class and the T is not define if the using clause if outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
using type_var = System.Int32;
```

---

As Eric Lippert points out in a comment, the algorithm which looks up type names on the right side of a `using` alias declaration does not take keywords, it takes identifiers.  Hence the need for `System.Int32` rather than `int`.

Comment: I assure you it is not. The algorithm which looks up type names on the right side of a "using" alias declaration does not take keywords, it takes identifiers.

Comment: @Eric I was using the OP's type names!

Comment: @David: `int` is a reserved word in C#. It cannot be used as an identifier. Nice try :P

Comment: @Eric Is there a good reason why the RHS of a using alias cannot process keywords like `int`? My curiosity is now piqued.

Comment: @David: The purpose of the feature is not to do a "typedef" that lets you give a different name to int. The purpose is to let you unambiguously shorten a name in an environment where a name collision would otherwise require a long fully-qualified name.

Comment: I've used this feature when consuming a library that defined an "Attribute" type to avoid collisions with the built-in type.  (Yes, the third party library probably should have chosen a name to avoid the collision.)